# How to have different cursor style for legends in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to have different cursor style for hover on legends in the Highcharts graph.

For example, legend `Series 1` should have `cursor:"default"` and `Series 2` should have `cursor:"pointer"`. when hovered.

How can I do that?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devnigel/p2x9yyvm/)

Comment: What you have tried? you have just copied jsfiddle link from highchart official site and pasted here

Comment: you can assign css styles to the pointers like:
.highcharts-point.highcharts-color-0 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
this is not totally waterproof. 
http://jsfiddle.net/p2x9yyvm/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define rules in the css like this:

```
.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-color-0 text {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-color-1 text {
    cursor: crosshair !important;
}
```

color-0 and color-1 corresponds to series 1 and series 2 respectively

Comment: I was so focused on finding solution using highcharts API that it didn't occur to me to use `!important` in the CSS solution I tried and gave up. Didn't really notice that I had added `css` tag to the question. But this works.